# PHP Array How to specify what order items should be

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How can I specify what order items should appear in an array?

I am given a 3 level array, somewhat like the following:

```
Array
(
[AK] => Array
    (
        [ACO] => Array
            (
                [FFS] => Array
                    (
                        [Medicaid] => -
                        [CHIP] => -
                    )
            )
        [ZCO] => Array
            (
                [FFS] => Array
                    (
                        [Medicaid] => -
                        [CHIP] => -
                    )
            )
        [Other] => Array
            (
                [FFS] => Array
                    (
                        [Medicaid] => -
                        [CHIP] => -
                    )
            )
    )
[AR] => Array
    (
        [Other] => Array
            (
                [Other] => Array
                    (
                        [Medicaid] => -
                        [CHIP] => -
                    )
            )
        [ACO] => Array
            (
                [FFS] => Array
                    (
                        [Medicaid] => -
                        [CHIP] => -
                    )

            )
        [ZCO] => Array
            (
                [FFS] => Array
                    (
                        [Medicaid] => -
                        [CHIP] => -
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

How can I make them sort list the first element `[AK]`, by the second level named element(I need them both to be `[ACO], [ZCO], [Other]`)?

Comment: You may need to write your own sort function : http://fr2.php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php

Comment: Is it that `Other` is always last, but other items are arbitrary or do you always have the same three elements `ACO`, `ZCO`, `Other`?

Comment: I actually have alot more items than this, but I wanted to keep it simple for the question.  Order needs to be exactly like the `[AK]` element, via `[ACO], [ZCO], [Other]`

Comment: You can either sort `AR` by the position of elements in `AK`, or you can devise a rule that would sort both as you want - ie sorting by length ascending and then normal ascending. Which would be best for your real problem? Also, do you know by what rule `AK` is sorted?

Comment: No rules.  The incoming array is a state list from a database table, pre-sorted on state. ie... `AK, AL, AR` etc...  like I said, I kept a bunch out of this to keep the question shorter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary is datastructure without order.

But **php** by default iterate items in order which elements been pasted.
So, you can simple recreate array in necessary order
Or write custom sort function using php [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) method.

small example:

```
function compare($a, $b) 
{
  $order = array('ACO', 'ZCO', 'Other');
  $ai = array_search($a, $order);
  $bi = array_search($b, $order);
  return $ai<$bi ? -1 : $ai>$bi;
}
$a = array('ZCO'=>1, 'Other'=>1, 'ACO'=>1);
uksort($a, "compare");
print_r($a);
```

Comment: not sure how I would do this... sorry, little bit of a rookie when coming to custom array sorting methods ;)

Comment: thanks for this.  I can't really tell if it has worked or not though.  Instead of displaying the `ACO, ZCO, Other` it is displaying the number of what I assume that particular items index is...

Comment: [uksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) You provide compare callback as second argument, which should return -1|0|1 - lower, equal, greater for any pair of keys..

Comment: I think we're close.  Now, it's in alpha order though by that 2nd key :)

Comment: will task solved, if you go through all first key by foreach and apply this method?

Answer (score 0):

```
// CREATE THE TEST DATA
$arr = Array
( 'AK' => Array
  ( 'ACO'   => Array( 'FFS' => Array( 'Medicaid' => '-', 'CHIP' => '-' ) )
  , 'ZCO'   => Array( 'FFS' => Array( 'Medicaid' => '-', 'CHIP' => '-' ) )
  , 'Other' => Array( 'FFS' => Array( 'Medicaid' => '-', 'CHIP' => '-' ) )
  )
, 'AR' => Array
  ( 'Other' => Array( 'FFS' => Array( 'Medicaid' => '-', 'CHIP' => '-' ) )
  , 'ACO'   => Array( 'FFS' => Array( 'Medicaid' => '-', 'CHIP' => '-' ) )
  , 'ZCO'   => Array( 'FFS' => Array( 'Medicaid' => '-', 'CHIP' => '-' ) )
  )
)
;

// ACTIVATE THIS TO ANSWER THE QUESTION: DOES IT LOOK RIGHT?
// print_r($arr);

// GET THE ORDER FOR THE [AK] ARRAY
$pat = array_keys($arr['AK']);

// ITERATE OVER THE ARRAY TO PRODUCE THE ORDERED OUTPUT
$out = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $inner)
{
    // SKIP THE SIGNAL ARRAY
    if ($key == 'AK')
    {
        $out[$key] = $inner;
        continue;
    }
    // REORDER THE OTHER ARRAYS
    else
    {
        $temp = array();
        foreach ($pat as $inner_key)
        {
            $temp[$inner_key] = $inner[$inner_key];
        }
        $out[$key] = $temp;
    }
}
// SHOW THE WORK PRODUCT
print_r($out);
```